# Using image as generic link background

Tags: css, background-image

How can I do to have an image as the background for all links? I want to have a nice box representing buttons, but I cannot figure this out.

I have tried:

```
a { 
    font-size: 40px;
    background: url('images/shooting-stars/shooting-star-link.png') no-repeat left top; 
}
```

But this is not working, image is not displaying.

Comment: Yeah I just figured my path was wrong... Thanks for your fast answer though! Any ideas on how can I do so that the image is always displayed completely? The text in the links is only a couple of letters and the background is not shown entirely.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment and turned it into an answer. Updated it with this new addition to your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I want to have a nice box representing buttons, but I cannot figure this out." - I don't understand this part.

Anyway, your css looks fine from here, are you sure the image exists? This is a working example with the exact same code, just an image that I'm sure exists:

http://jsfiddle.net/3k9nm/

If you want to always show the image, even if the text is shorter, you should set a minimum width for the links. This does mean they'll have to be inline-blocks, you can't set width on a regular link (which is an inline element).

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 25px;  
}
```

(25px was randomly chosen, fill in the width of your background image..)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try, is there any text in the actual `<a>` links? And if you use Firebug, you can check you've definitely got the right file path to the image...

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div id="example-link">
  <a href="#">Link to journal article</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#example-link a { 

  background: url('images/shooting-stars/shooting-star-link.png'); 
}
```

Comment: What's with the wrapping div and the totally arbitrary 3px 1px positioning?